# Is there something like parse_url in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, parse-url

Is there there somethings like parse_url() equivalent in Objective C?

I like the simplicity of this function in PHP and need the same thing in an iPhone app. For example:
given a url http://www.google.com/?someting=somthing

I can get a nice data structure with the host, protocol, base url...etc, without having to create parse strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There’s [`NSURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can create an `NSURL` from a string and then use methods like `baseURL`, `path`, `query`, etc.